# Process multiple files one by one dynamically in workflow using indirect file method

Tags: ksh, informatica, informatica-powercenter

My workflow uses 3 indirect files.
The indirect files can have one or more file names.
Let's say all 3 indirect files have 2 file names each.

```
Indirect_file1 has (file1,file2)
Indirect_file2 has (filea,fileb)
Indirect_file3 has (filex,filey)
```

My workflow should run in sequence.

```
First  sequence (file1,filea,filex) 
Second sequence (file2,fileb,filey)
```

we are on Linux environment, so i guess it can be done using shell script

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work -

1. in informatica session, modify input type to 'Command'
2. in informatica session, change command type to 'Command generating file List'
3. for first worfklow set the command like this 'cut -d ',' file -f1' if your delimiter is comma.
4. for second worfklow set the command like this 'cut -d ',' file -f2' if your delimiter is comma.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to make small work packages first before processing. When the workflow takes a long time it is easier to (re-)start new processes.
You can start with something like this:

```
# Step 1, move the current set to temporary folder
combine_dir=/tmp/combine
mkdir "${combine_dir}"
mv Indirect_file1 "${combine_dir}"
mv Indirect_file2 "${combine_dir}"
mv Indirect_file3 "${combine_dir}"
# Step 2, construct work packages in other tmp dir
workload_dir=/tmp/workload
mkdir "${workload_dir}"
for file in Indirect_file1 Indirect_file2 Indirect_file3; do
   loadnr=1
   for work in $(grep -Eo '[^(,)]*' "${file}"); do
      echo "${work}" >> ${workload_dir}/sequence${loadnr}
      ((loadnr++))
   done
done
# The sequenceXXX files have been generated with one file on each line.
# When you must have it like (file1,filea,filex), change above loop.
# Now files are ready to be processed. Move them to some dir where files will be handled.
# Please cleanup temporary files
```

Comment: This script will not be helpful to execute informatica workflow in sequence. This script is valid and perfectly good only to combine the files in sequence. But the requirement is to combine the file and execute the workflow in sequence according to the number of file names in both the files

Comment: @JimMacaulay I do not understand the informatica workflow requirements. When the indirect_files have 20 files, my script will generate 20 new files, each one with the files with the same position in the indrect files. Next step can be executing the files in sequence.